# Why doesn't the Jin Nadakhan take out the ninja when they sleep?

Tags: lego, lego-ninjago-masters-of-spinjitzu

In the *Lego Ninjago: Masters of Spinjitzu* series why doesn't Jin the Nadakhan take out the ninja when they sleep?